# Why is this react-router not routing correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've used this same set up in other react apps I've made and for the life of me I can't figure out why this no longer works. I notice it's a later version of react-router but it shouldn't have breaking changes from what I read.

When I try to go to the /tweets route I get the error

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`

If I go to /tweets2 route it passes me to the 404 NotFound Route.

All non authenticated routes seem to work as expected.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Login from './views/login/LoginPage.js';
import Logout from './views/logout/LogoutPage';
import TweetList from './views/tweets/tweetList';
import NotFound from './views/notfound/NotFoundPage';
import './App.css';


function loggedIn() {
  console.log("loggedIn() was called")
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  let timestamp = localStorage.getItem('timestamp');
  let potentialExp = timestamp/1000 + 7200; // 2 hours after token was created in seconds
  /*Checks if there's a token in local storage and if the timestamp is older than 2 hours.
    These are simply quick front end checks. All auth is really done server side.
  */
  if( token != null && timestamp != null && potentialExp > new Date().getTime()/1000){
    console.log("the user met logged in condition")
    return true;
   }else{
    console.log(" the user did NOT meet logged in condition")
    return false
   }
}
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#8551fd',
      main: '#814ff8',
      dark: '#051550',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#f2f7fe',
      main: '#B0BEC5',
      dark: '#B0BEC5',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
  }
});

const PrimaryLayout = () => (
  <div className="primary-layout">
  <main>
  <Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />

  <Route path="/tweets" exact render={(passedProps) => (
    !loggedIn() ? (
      <Redirect to={`/login`}/>
    ) : (
      <TweetList {...this.props = passedProps}/>
    )
  )}/>

  <Route path="/tweets2" exact render={(props) => (
    !loggedIn() ? (
      <Redirect to={`/login`}/>
    ) : (
      <TweetList {...props}/>
    )
  )}/>

  <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
  <Route exact component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
  </main>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <PrimaryLayout />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

export default App;
```

Comment: The line `<TweetList {...this.props = passedProps}/>` is throwing error because `this` is undefined here. Why don't you directly pass it like `<TweetList {...passedProps}/>`

Comment: I tried that   `<Route path="/tweets" exact render={(passedProps) => (
      <TweetList {...passedProps}/>
  )}/>`
and it just passed me to the catch all not found route.

Comment: This is also the case for not passing any props at all

 `<Route path="/tweets" exact render={(passedProps) => (
      <TweetList />
  )}/>`

Comment: Where is definition of `/login` route? It seems like they are being redirected to `/login` and since there is no definition of `/login`, they all fallback to not found route.

Comment: I had that thought too but I removed the login check entirely and still no dice :(

Comment: Okay I figured out the issue. I was calling the wrong component inside `<TweetList/>` However, I'm still not sure why `this` is undefined in the `/tweets` path. it's not in my other react apps